# How to open the cover of flush mounted ceiling light dome to change light bulb

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture, bulb

I have mounted ceiling light dome that can't twist, pull, push or open in order to change light bulb.
It looks like this:
[image]
[image]

I have tried twisting it counter-clockwise,clockwise with bear hands, with latex glows, tried pulling it down and nothing moves it one bit. I have noticed 3 small holes on the upper side that are visible on the second picture, but because of there position and size it is impossible to reach screws (if there are any) with screwdriver.
I don't even know what model is this light-fixture, because I moved in new apartment recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have called electrician. He twisted it real hard something snapped and opened. But after he changed light bulb and closed light dome again something break so that he wasn't able to opened it again. 
You can open it with offset screwdriver, but it was not designed to be open like that.

Answer (score 1):

They may be set screws which would normally require  an Allen driver. That would give you access with the short part of the proper sized Allen driver.

Comment: It could also be a small standard slotted or Phillips type screw

Comment: Very true it could need an offset screwdriver but that would be a horrible design.  It's not a very good design anyway but I would hope they would use an Allen head since it's a blind fastener and having Allen wrenches are generally more common in a toolbox than offset screwdrivers. Either way the tool needed would have a 90deg bend and a short shaft before the necessary driver head.

Comment: I have used mirror and flashlight to see what is hidden in that hole. It was a phillips screw. So I need offset screwdrivers.

Comment: If there's space to fit a ratchet with a Phillips drive it would be faster but it looks pretty tight.